# Angular 2+ Binding - WebAPI - Cannot read property 'Username' of undefined

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, binding, undefined, typeerror

I'm trying to do the binding in my angular application.

On my component.html i have:

```
<span>{{this.test.Username}}</span>
```

And this is my component.ts:

```
export class NavbarComponent implements AfterViewChecked, OnInit{     

   test: User;

   constructor(private userService: UserService) {                                                 
   }   

   ngOnInit() {
      var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
      var id = currentUser.userID;        
      this.userService.getById(id).subscribe(user => {                        
        this.test = new User();
        this.test = user;            
      });                 
   }
}
```

In reality, the binding works and the Username appears on the client side, 
but the problem is that the browser returns this error:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'Username' of undefined
at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (NavbarComponent.html:79)
at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:11087)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10463)
at callViewAction (core.js:10699)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10641)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10464)
at callViewAction (core.js:10699)
at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10641)
at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10464)
at callViewAction (core.js:10699)
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the initial value to `test`

```
test: User = { Username : null };
```

Or use the optional operator in the template

```
<span>{{this.test?.Username}}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `User` is a class, initialize in `constructor`

```
 this.test = new User();
```